# Word/Phrase for becoming smarter through one's experiences

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single word or phrase for becoming more learned/smarter/knowledgeable through one's experiences?

The particular sentence I want it for is:

> A child becomes ____ as it grows older and interacts with its surroundings.

Comment: Mispelled "particular".

Comment: No single word covers all that.  A child becomes more sophisticated and more savvy through experience.  Does growing older really help, or is twhat else goes on?

Comment: Surely, "A child becomes **experienced** as it grows older..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'**mature**' is what I finally came up with.

Answer (score 2):

**learns**

> A child **learns** through interaction.

This is, in my opinion, far more concise, and your readers should thank you for it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing [wisdom](https://www.google.com/search?q=wisdom).

A child becomes ***wise*** as it grows older and interacts with its surroundings.

Often used in the context of a particular aspect of the environment. *Wise in the ways of men*, for example.

https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wise+in+the+ways+of%22

> **Wisdom**: the quality of having experience, knowledge, and good judgment; the quality of being wise.
>   synonyms:   sagacity, intelligence, sense, common sense, shrewdness, astuteness, smartness, judiciousness, judgment, prudence, circumspection; More
>   ***the soundness of an action or decision with regard to the application of experience, knowledge, and good judgment***.